# Can anybody help me out why output of below code snippet is X88?

Tags: java

Can anybody explain to me the code snippet below?

```
 class G{
      public static void main(String [] args)
        {
               char x='X';
               int i=0; 
              System.out.print(true ? x : 0);
              System.out.print(false ? i: x);

     }
    }
```

Comment: What's your best theory?

Comment: I couldnt understand your question

Comment: @Giri, I believe Andrew was just trying to push you into thinking a bit more on the problem...

Comment: @Frankie:  Heck yes.  This is not a help desk.  To ask a [smart question](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html), you'd include code (done), ask a specific question (covered), describe the output expected **(missing)** & the actual output (done).  For extra points, describe *why* you felt the output should be as you expected.

Answer (score 3):

On the second statement `false ? i: x` you're comparing different types.

`int : char` makes the char 'X' print out as `int`. And `X`'s ASCII code is 88`.

Answer (score 2):

Your x is automatically casted from char to int. Try the following code and 88 will be printed.

```
System.out.println((int)'X');
```